# How to write a shortcode with variable to display content from specific custom post type post?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, shortcode

I've only written very basic shortcodes without variables and am just not figuring out how to write one that allows someone to enter a variable to pull info from a specific post.

I have a custom post type called "Events". I want to put a shortcode on the site FrontPage that will display the contents of a specific event within that custom post type. I'm assuming a variable is the way to do this, but I don't know what the best way is. Should I be having the user find the post ID number to use as the variable? Note that I am not trying to display an arcive of the post type, only the contents of a specific post, as indicated by the shortcode variable. I can see something like the following, but don't know how to achieve it:

[display-event id="77"]

Really, this is advanced for me, so any direction you can give me would be much appreciated.

~Laura

Comment: Hey Laura, this is a very similar question to this one http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9729/how-would-i-create-a-shortcode-to-display-a-custom-post-within-a-page-or-regular You can probably modify the code in the accepted answer there to fit your needs. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at WordPress's documentation for add_shortcode().

You would need to add something like the following in your functions.php file:-

```
function baztag_func( $atts, $content = "" ) {
    // What you would like your short code to do

    return "content = $content";
}
add_shortcode( 'baztag', 'baztag_func' );
```

[add_shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Comment: Again, I've written *basic* shortcodes like what you've mentioned, and I've referenced the documentation for writing shortcodes with certain types of variables. I just don't know how to apply this concept to writing a shortcode.